# Docker build falla al importar un módulo de Go en un repositorio privado: The command '/bin/sh -c go mod vendor' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker, go

Estoy teniendo problemas al construir una imagen de Docker, se queda en el siguiente paso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine3.14
    
    ENV GO111MODULE=on \
        CGO_ENABLED=1  \
        GOARCH="amd64" \
        GOOS=linux
    
    RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates tzdata curl git gcc musl-dev
    
    RUN mkdir -p /go/src/stores-redis-replicator
    WORKDIR /go/src/stores-redis-replicator
    ADD . .
    RUN go mod vendor
    RUN go build -a -tags="musl netgo" --ldflags "-extldflags -static -w" -installsuffix cgo -o app .
    
    FROM alpine:3.14
    RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates tzdata
    COPY --from=0 /go/src/stores-redis-replicator .
    ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

No entiendo muy bien por qué se queda en ese paso.

Comment: En el futuro no hagas capturas de pantalla, copia y pega directamente en la pregunta, le harás la vida más fácil a quien te intente ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si miras el error que te está dando, no es el que indicas en la pregunta, es el siguiente:

```
stores-redis-replicator/http imports bitbucket.org/rappinc/core-go-apm/apm:
reading bitbucket.org/rappinc/core-go-apm/go.mod at revision v0.0.8:
git ls- remote -q origin in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/b067a2e16ec5096668cc09393a0a1c92ef8546 Oaceb8da4146cb4bd2cd451e0c: 
exit status 128: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': 
terminal prompts disabled Confirm the import path was entered correctly. 
this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

y la parte importante es esta:

```
could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': 
terminal prompts disabled Confirm the import path was entered correctly. 
this is a private repository
```

Básicamente lo que te está diciendo es que el modulo que estás compilando dentro de tu contenedor de docker `stores-redis-replicator` importa un dependecia que está alojada en un repositorio privado en `bitbucket` y no te estás autenticando para poder descargarlo y por eso el build falla.

Aqui: [Fetching Private Go Modules During Docker Build](https://jwenz723.medium.com/fetching-private-go-modules-during-docker-build-5b76aa690280) tienes un ejemplo de como arreglarlo. El resumen es que tienes que crear un `access token` y añadir la autenticación al `dockerfile`.

Comment: Gracias amigo pablo, trate de replicar lo que decia el documento y me funciona, lo que indicas era el problema que estaba teniendo

Comment: Pues si te ha ayudado, por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada